# IntelliJ to use maven when running the project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to force Intellij to use maven pom.xml to compile project and run using artifacts from target directory?

**UPDATE:**

I'll describe why I need this. There are lot of configurations in maven pom.xml like copying target jar file to some location, post compile aspect weaving. But Intellij does not care about all this, thus I need it to use maven pom.xml to compile and then run.

Comment: Actually, Idea can care about pre and post compile maven tasks. You just need to configure intellij to run the tasks in the run configuration or in the maven window.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this by adding a maven run configuration and execute with the `clean install exec:java` goals

Comment: So if I want to execute some java file except main, i'll need to modify maven file and then run it?

Comment: no, actually you can do `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"` as per the docs this shoud work
http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: You can do this, but it really seems suboptimal to run your app via maven every time.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know about that feature, so thanks, I just used it on the weekend :)

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on a lifecycle step (or a group of selected steps) in the maven project window you can choose to execute that step before or after make, rebuild, or run/debug. Further, if you look at the run configuration for your main method you'll see a section of the panel called Before Launch: Make, where you can add arbitrary maven tasks to be invoked before the app is launched. I find this approach preferable to running my app via maven, because it allows easier debugging and doesn't need complex maven command lines.

Comment: I didn't know about this functionality, but anyway it does not solve the problem. I need to integrate aspectj (but avoid compile time weaving). For example I create a test and run that particular test, If i use maven I'll have to edit pom file every single time i change configurations. If I use your described feature, it will run maven tasks but It will use its own build system to build and run stuff. I was using compile time weaving but it had lot of bugs for java 1.8

Comment: There are no circumstances under which you have to edit the pom file to change configuration. That's what profiles are for, and this technique will happily use whichever profile you need for your given task. Nothing in this approach stops you from running specific tests -- you can set up a default configuration for that which includes your pre-post build steps by default.